# Highchart does not render when enabling Localization in my project

Tags: ios, swift, highcharts, localization

I have a released IOS app using HighChart v. 7.2. I'm now trying to localize the app to Spanish and French etc. by localizing my Localizable.strings.

When I run the app on the iPhone simulator with the iPhone language is set to Spanish the Highchart does not render. French is ok. Some languages work but most does not. I have not changed any strings in the language-specific files so they are still all English.

Any hints are highly appreciated.

Comment: Hi Christian, welcome to StackOverflow.  Can you include snippets of the pertinent language file settings in your question? Are there any error messages in the web browser logs, reported during execution of the HighCharts code? I've never worked with iOS before, and your question as-is is overly broad to be answerable on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry :-) Found the issue in my own code. I was passing a bad Moment format string in the tooltip formatter.